# Validate an integer with a specific 0-65536 range in Regex C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to learning Regex and I have tried almost everything myself and from the internet to find a Regex that accepts values from 0 to 65536 and yes I want to do it by Regex only. The Closest I got was 69999.

Comment: _The Closest I got was 69999_ What do you mean by that? What have you tried so far? Why don't you use simple numeric comparison and doing your work more complicate (probably) with regex?

Comment: Regular expressions are generaly good for extracting data, not for some validation if it. So why don't extract that integer and then check if it's in desired bounds?

Comment: Also, you can google 'Regex generator for number range' and you get [this site](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range).

Comment: I'm actually surprised that web page exists, Jerry... OP, exactly why does it need to use regex? Is this a learning exercise? it doesn't seem like something you should be using regex for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
^(?:[0-5]?[0-9]{1,4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-6])$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJ4tP3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Split it into multiple ranges: 0-9, 10-9999, 10000-59999, 60000-64999, 65000-65499, 65500-65529, 65530-65536

```
^(?:\d|[1-9]\d{1,3}|[1-5]\d{4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-6])$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]